# intrinsic tick count, a fine performance measurement no need for external api

Tags: c++, c, performance-testing

taking minimal steps to question how a given code perform(a fast one), isn't
that the smallest unit, most fine measurment?

```
#pragma intrinsic(__rdtsc)

int main(void)
{
    ULONGLONG t1,t2;

    t1= __rdtsc();
    work();
    t2= __rdtsc();
    std::cout<<t2-t1<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `rdtsc` is x86-specfic, may trap into the OS, doesn't serialize, is not well-specified (some cpu's count in cycles, others in constant increments, which may be different, due to variable clockspeed). No, this *doesn't* give you an accurate measurement.

Comment: Gives the clock cycles since reset. Since there are many processes running, it's no measurement of the performance of *one* process.

Comment: It is useless as-is, you still are going to need to invoke an oracle that tells you what one tick means.  Its length is not the same from machine to another.

Comment: @EOF in x86 `rdtsc` will not trap into the OS. I don't know if emulations on other platforms exist, that will, but not on x86. It is just a way to produce exacly one defined Assembler instruction: `RDTSC`.

Comment: @cdonat Whether it traps depends on cr4.tsd; see e g. http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDTSC.html

Comment: @AlanStokes Oh, I didn't know that one. I never came across that in real life on Linux systems. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter is worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

the man page, found at: http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime gives all the details.

you want to be calling the `clock_gettime()` function

to get just the time for your process, use:

```
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, struct timespec * );
```

or for the current thread use:

```
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, struct timespec * );
```

returns 0 for success, or -1 for failure (in which case errno is set appropriately).

The struct timespec is defined as:

```
struct timespec 
{
    time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

All the above is defined in the header file: `time.h`

Comment: hey, r u on linux or windows, is that an issue at all? i work with windows 7 & vs 2010 native c++

Comment: I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04 with gcc on a AMD x86-64  CPU with 10 cores.  I have not used `clock_gettime()` on a windows OS, so it might have a different name; however, it is still the C language so I expect it to be the same name

Comment: not intel and not windows, one of my best friends is like you... .to the point of the question though... this should be further examined (;

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to measure. It does not necessarily give you any information about the elapsed time. That depends on the concrete x86 implementation. It gives you the number of "ticks" elapsed, with different definition of "ticks". It might be the more or less constant maximum clock frequency or the actually used frequency.

To make `rdtsc` usable for performance measurements of small core fragments, you also have to make sure, that the OS does not preempt your thread, or move it to another core, that might have a different TSC value. Use CPU binding and CPU shielding for your performance measurement thread. Also consider the difference between cold and warm performance testing. Chose wisely between the two depending on your use case.

In a team, I have worked a few years ago, we used it that way and it did give us good, rather stable and reproducible results, since we took care of all these other issues as well: warm tests with CPU binding and CPU shielding.

Comment: by the time it took me to research "Shielded CPU"  i allready invented an idea of what if it could be possible to make say 8 cores CPU and dedicate 4 to the user, unless you specifically assign the 4 slipping CPU's to your specific program they are asleep and never interupted, i didn't know of RTOS , and that that's one of the strong fitures of UNIX. i guess there should be a spesific pc for testing, 8 cores, with say windows os specified for testings where the os is aware to those conditions